# Want to show two items in each row with equal distance in collection view perfectly in All devices ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have collection view want to show two items in each cell with equal distance in **All devices** ios programatically. please help me I have spend lot of time on it.refer below screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It will be helpful if you put your tried out code along with your question

Comment: or some picture showing what really you want

Comment: Can you post your tried code and result of what you have achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to set the size of each item. Try this `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Check the below code for reference :

```
UICollectionView *col = [[UICollectionView alloc]init];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
[layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)]; // Change item size as per your requirements.
col.collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

Check it and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: what is the issue?